# Create ETag filter in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, filter, etag

I would like to create an ETag filter in MVC.
The problem is that I can't control the Response.OutputStream, if I was able to do that I would simply calculate the ETag according to the result stream.
I did this thing before in WCF but couldn't find any simple idea to do that in MVC.

I want to be able to write something like that

```
[ETag]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var myModel = Factory.CreateModel();
    return View(myModel);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean you want the ETag to represent the actual stream content, such as a hash of the stream contents?

Comment: Yes, I want to ETag cache according to the Model. When I don't know the model type - just want be able to add Etag to any result.

Comment: @anativ - You should really avoid using the OutputStream as a way to generate the ETag. This is because you'll need to regenerate the response each time, even if nothing changes. A much more efficient way to do this is to hash all the parameters that are used to construct the output stream, and use this as your Etag value. This allows you to bypass expensive processing if the client already has a copy of the content.

Comment: @Andrew Theken - that is, if your content does not change, given the input parameters. But the purpose of the ETag is exactly in knowing if the content has not changed since the client requested it. If you're doing that, you are completely missing the point of using an ETag in the first place: you just need a client side cache that nevere ever expires. jm2c.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks a lot it is exactly what I was looking for.
Just made a small fix to the ETagFilter that will handle 304 in case that the content wasn't changed

```
public class ETagAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new ETagFilter(filterContext.HttpContext.Response, filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request);
    }
}

public class ETagFilter : MemoryStream
{
    private HttpResponseBase _response = null;
    private HttpRequestBase _request;
    private Stream _filter = null;

    public ETagFilter(HttpResponseBase response, HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        _response = response;
        _request = request;
        _filter = response.Filter;
    }

    private string GetToken(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] checksum = new byte[0];
        checksum = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(stream);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(checksum, 0, checksum.Length);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[count];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, data, 0, count);
        var token = GetToken(new MemoryStream(data));

        string clientToken = _request.Headers["If-None-Match"];

        if (token != clientToken)
        {
            _response.Headers["ETag"] = token;
            _filter.Write(data, 0, count);
        }
        else
        {
            _response.SuppressContent = true;
            _response.StatusCode = 304;
            _response.StatusDescription = "Not Modified";
            _response.Headers["Content-Length"] = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is have the matter: Multiple calls “Write”, response etag very long.

Comment: it won't be very long because of md5 checksum. But it will be called multiple times which can hurt performance.

Answer (score 27):

This is the best I could come up with, I didn't really understand what you meant by you can't control the Response.OutputStream.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class ETagAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string GetToken(Stream stream) {
        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
        byte [] checksum = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(checksum, 0, checksum.Length);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("ETag", GetToken(filterContext.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream));
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

This should work, but is doesn't.

Apparently Microsoft overrode System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) so that it returns "Specified method is not supported.", not sure why they would do that, since it inherits for the System.IO.Stream base class...

Which is mix up of the following resources, the Response.OutputStream is a write only stream, so we have to use a Response.Filter class to read the output stream, kind of quirky that you have to use a filter on a filter, but it works =)

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/494721-md5-encryption-question-communication-java
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/Calculating_MD5_Checksum.aspx
http://blog.gregbrant.com/post/Adding-Custom-HTTP-Headers-to-an-ASPNET-MVC-Response.aspx
http://www.infoq.com/articles/etags
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

**Update**

After much fighting I was finally able to get this to work:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class ETagAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        try {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new ETagFilter(filterContext.HttpContext.Response);
        } catch (System.Exception) {
            // Do Nothing
        };
    }
}

public class ETagFilter : MemoryStream {
    private HttpResponseBase o = null;
    private Stream filter = null;

    public ETagFilter (HttpResponseBase response) {
        o = response;
        filter = response.Filter;
    }

    private string GetToken(Stream stream) {
        byte[] checksum = new byte[0];
        checksum = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(stream);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(checksum, 0, checksum.Length);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
        byte[] data = new byte[count];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, data, 0, count);
        filter.Write(data, 0, count);
        o.AddHeader("ETag", GetToken(new MemoryStream(data)));
    }
}
```

More Resources:

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/Web/HttpResponseClassFilter.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1380989.aspx/1

Comment: I'm not sure this link really helps. The OP has asked a specific question about calculating an ETag value from the contents of a Model class, which may have nothing to do with the file dependencies approach in the link. From my reading of the question, the OP either wants to calculate the ETag value from an arbitrary model object, or from the OutputStream itself. In either case, this suggestion does not seem offer any help.

Comment: @anativ, not 100% sure how to do this with the Model class, but I did figure out a way to do with Response.OutputStream.

Comment: Watch out. This might look that it is working but it does not work for every scenario. This is working only if the Response is done inside a single block of write. This is not the case when the file is big because the stream will buffer the writing in multiple chunk. That say, the AddHeader and GetToken would be called more than once.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few promising answers. But none of them is complete solution. Also it was not part of the question and nobody mentioned it. But *ETag should be used for Cache validation. Therefore it should be used with Cache-Control header*. So clients don't even have to call the server until the cache expires (it can be very short period of time depends on your resource). When the cache expired then client makes a request with ETag and validate it. For more details about caching [see this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching).

Here is my CacheControl attribute solution with ETags. It can be improved e.g. with Public cache enabled, etc... *However I strongly advise you to understand caching and modify it carefully. If you use HTTPS and the endpoints are secured then this setup should be fine.*

```
/// <summary>
/// Enables HTTP Response CacheControl management with ETag values.
/// </summary>
public class ClientCacheWithEtagAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _clientCache;

    private readonly HttpMethod[] _supportedRequestMethods = {
        HttpMethod.Get,
        HttpMethod.Head
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientCacheInSeconds">Indicates for how long the client should cache the response. The value is in seconds</param>
    public ClientCacheWithEtagAttribute(int clientCacheInSeconds)
    {
        _clientCache = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(clientCacheInSeconds);
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!_supportedRequestMethods.Contains(actionExecutedContext.Request.Method))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response?.Content == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var body = await actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (body == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var computedEntityTag = GetETag(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));

        if (actionExecutedContext.Request.Headers.IfNoneMatch.Any()
            && actionExecutedContext.Request.Headers.IfNoneMatch.First().Tag.Trim('"').Equals(computedEntityTag, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotModified;
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = null;
        }

        var cacheControlHeader = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            Private = true,
            MaxAge = _clientCache
        };

        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.ETag = new EntityTagHeaderValue($"\"{computedEntityTag}\"", false);
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl = cacheControlHeader;
    }

    private static string GetETag(byte[] contentBytes)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(contentBytes);
            string hex = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
            return hex.Replace("-", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage e.g: with 1 min client side caching:

```
[ClientCacheWithEtag(60)]
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the code i created to solve this problem - i inherit from gzip because i want to gzip the stream as well ( you can always use a regular stream)
the difference is that i calculate the etag for all my response and not just chunk of it.

```
public class ETagFilter : GZipStream
{
    private readonly HttpResponseBase m_Response;
    private readonly HttpRequestBase m_Request;
    private readonly MD5 m_Md5;
    private bool m_FinalBlock;



    public ETagFilter(HttpResponseBase response, HttpRequestBase request)
        : base(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress)
    {
        m_Response = response;
        m_Request = request;
        m_Md5 = MD5.Create();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        m_Md5.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private string ByteArrayToString(byte[] arrInput)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder(arrInput.Length);
        for (var i = 0; i < arrInput.Length; i++)
        {
            output.Append(arrInput[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        m_Md5.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null, 0);
        base.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        if (m_FinalBlock)
        {
            base.Flush();
            return;
        }
        m_FinalBlock = true;
        m_Md5.TransformFinalBlock(new byte[0], 0, 0);
        var token = ByteArrayToString(m_Md5.Hash);
        string clientToken = m_Request.Headers["If-None-Match"];

        if (token != clientToken)
        {
            m_Response.Headers["ETag"] = token;
        }
        else
        {
            m_Response.SuppressContent = true;
            m_Response.StatusCode = 304;
            m_Response.StatusDescription = "Not Modified";
            m_Response.Headers["Content-Length"] = "0";
        }
        base.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution looks promising, but I could not get it to work (I only get gibberish in the response). Can you post the complete code for the Attribute?

Comment: @TNT pay attention that i inherit from gzipStream. you probably not gzip you content or not passing the header that the response is gziped.