# How can I handle ETag in aspnet mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, performance, asp.net-mvc-5, etag

Yslow and PageSpeed suggested to use ETags for my website performance.
I tried that [Create ETag filter in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642815/create-etag-filter-in-asp-net-mvc) but I am getting the blank page...

Is there any other simple way I can handle ETags?

The website will be hosted on shared hosting environment.
I think the custom filters is the best way to go.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to implement a Nuget package like [CacheCow](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekASPNETWebAPICachingWithCacheCowAndCacheOutput.aspx) or CacheOutput.